# Wordpress facetWp

Tags: php, wordpress, facetwp

I'm doing something like this with facetWP.

http://www.scrambledchefs.com/recipe-index/recipe-browser/?fwp_meal_type=main-dish

And i want my pictures to stay like this website.
here is my PHP code to see what i have done:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( '' ); ?>
  </a></p>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>', '</center>' ); ?></a></p>
  <a/></p>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Right now they are shown one under the other i want to show them like the website i have post (grid view).

Answer (score 0):

From your code example one might think that you lack some basics. The loop content should be wrapped in `<div>` or `<article>` tags. Then you can add the maximal width to this element. For example `max-width: 33.3333%;` and maybe `float: left;`.